# removing xml attributes with php - abnormal xml

Tags: php, xml

I created an ios app that parses an xml document. If a user logs in, their information will be added to the xml file. I would like to be able to remove a user if they are logging out or cancelling their logins. Essentially, I need to figure out how to delete an xml object (a user, in this case) that looks like this:

```
<users>
    <user>
        <fname>fname1</fname>
        <lname>lname1</lname>
    </user>
    <user>
        <fname>fname2</fname>
        <lname>lname2</lname>
    </user>
</users>
```

For example, I may want to remove a user based on the last name, which will always be unique in my case... This is the php that I have so far, but I am completely open to suggestions on doing it a different way

```
$deletefname = $row['fname'];
$deletelname = $row['lname'];
$deleteimageurl = $row['imageURL'];

$xmlUrl = "thefile.xml"; // XML 
$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
foreach($xml->users as $user)
{
    if($user[$fname] == $deletefname) {
        $xml=dom_import_simplexml($user);
        $xml->parentNode->removeChild($xml);    
    }
}


$xml->asXML('newfile.xml');
echo $xml;
```

I am very bad with php, and I took this code from someone else. Not 100% sure how it works.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wait, what node are you trying to remove?

Comment: I am trying to delete an entire user. based on their first name in this case.

Comment: u said last name. which one is it

Comment: You can use RapidXML free and it's robust already.

Comment: @SinisterRainbow what is the point of programming if your going to use a tool that doesn't teach you anything?

Comment: @RPM You mean - what's the point of code reuse? He may have a larger project in mind rather than 'learning to make an XML parser'. If that's the case, there are XML parsers that are fast, robust, and will save him days of coding when that may not be his goal.

Comment: I am assuming he wants to automate the process of manipulating an XML file. So if not, then there is a point in using Rapid XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
/*
 * @source_file -- source to your xml document
 * @node_to_remove -- your node
 * Note this will remove an entire user from the source file if the argument (node_to_remove)
   matches a nodes node value
 *
 */
function newFunction($source_file,$node_to_remove) {
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load($source_file);
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->formatOutput = true; 
    foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('users') as $users ) 
    {
        foreach($users->getElementsByTagName('user') as $user) {

            $first_name = $user->getElementsByTagName('fname')->item(0);

            if($first_name->nodeValue == $node_to_remove) {


                $users->removeChild($users->getElementsByTagName('user')->item(0));

            }

        }

    }

    $result = $xml->saveXML();

    return $result;

}


echo newFunction('xml.xml','lname1');
?>
```

Comment: what is item(0) actually referring to?

Comment: It is an instance of DOMNode.

Comment: So did this answer your question? I believe it did. If so, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Before I start, I will give the usual warning that an XML file is not a database and you should use a real database (mysql, sqlite, an xml database) or at least file locking ([`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)) or atomic writes (writing to a temporary file then [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to the real name). If you don't, you will get into situations where one request is reading the file as another one is writing it and get garbage XML.

You can do this with `SimpleXML` or with `DOMDocument`, and with either one you can use xpath or iteration.

Below is the `SimpleXMLElement` method because that is what your code uses.

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
// XPATH
$matches = $sxe->xpath('/users/user[lname="lname2"]');
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    unset($match[0]);
}
// Iteration--slower, but safer if a part of the path is dynamic (e.g. "lname2")
// because xpath literals are very hard to escape.
// be sure to iterate backwards
for ($i=$sxe->user->count()-1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
    if ($sxe->user[$i]->lname=='lname2') {
        unset($sxe->user[$i]);
    }
}

echo $sxe->asXML();
```

Comment: Francis, do you know any good resources that will show me how to convert the xml to a database? Do you know if this will make it a much more difficult for the iOS portion?

Comment: You don't say much about the overall design so I can't comment on difficulty viz iOS. If you have a url interface between client and server what backend you use on the server shouldn't affect a clean design. You can still serve the same XML, just store it differently.

Comment: If a user is trying to read the xml while it is being written, what will happen?

Comment: The reader will read a half-written file. What happens exactly is unpredictable. It's no different than any concurrent file access. E.g. 100 byte file, if writer has written 50 bytes, reader will see only 50 bytes, or maybe he will see 50 new bytes and 50 old bytes (depending on exactly how the writer is writing). Either way, XML is garbage, either unparsable or (worse) inconsistent.